# Unexpected user input onclick

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to fix this. It says the onclick is missing a semi-colon.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious - any ideas?

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com" onclick="setTimeout(location.href='https://www.facebook.com/myprofile', 10);return true;">
```

Comment: Trying to squeeze that much code into an onclick, or arguably even using onclick at all, is your first problem.  Move it to the pages script file.

Comment: `setTimeout` expects to be passed a function. You are passing a string (`"https://www.facebook.com/myprofile"`), which gets `eval`d as JavaScript code, but that string doesn't contain JavaScript, so an error is thrown.

Comment: Expanding on @LukePark 's comment about onclick - agree, avoid using `onclick=` and instead learn how to attach event handlers by using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or with a toolkit such as jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Your `setTimeout` syntax is invalid, it should be:

```
setTimeout(function() { location.href='https://www.facebook.com/myprofile'; }, 10);
```